# What are squares of carpet called?

Tags: flooring

The carpeting in the hotel room is actually a set of rectangles that are glued to the floor. I would like to purchase/evaluate these carpet 'tiles' for use in a rental housing.

Does this class of flooring have a name that I can google?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are actually called [carpet tiles](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Flooring-Carpet-Carpet-Tile/N-5yc1vZbo4w). They have some definite advantages over traditional wall-to-wall carpeting:

- Easier to install
- Can install without moving everything out of the room
- Can be repaired a tile at a time if needed (provided you have spare tiles, and the color of a tile sitting in the box for a few years may not exactly match the color of tiles that have been sitting out in light and air and underfoot)

and some disadvantages:

- Even with professional installation, there can be problems with tiles coming up at the edges
- The seams are sometimes a bit too visible (obviously not an issue if you have multiple colors/patterns next to each other)

Comment: As for stored tiles being different due to aging / sunlight then tiles can be moved form one area to another and the "new" ones "hidden" behind things...